# SIGSEGV error when returning a new object

Tags: c++

I am attempting a minecraft clone, and I have spent the past 3 hours debugging a SIGSEGV error. I've traced it to returning a new object. `return Block(BlockID::Air)` for example. When I run my debugging tool, it leads to move.h:

```
...
 // concept requirements
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_SGIAssignableConcept<_Tp>)

  _Tp __tmp = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__a);
  __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
  __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
}
...
```

I also get the error whenever I create a new glm::vec3

Comment: SIGSEGV is a result of accessing memory you aren't allowed to. Generally the place where the _actual crash_ happens is not the site of the _actual cause_. Certainly the minimal code you've provided from (what looks like?) a library function isn't the culprit. Can you post the code/function being called that's actually yours? My first guess would be that you're returning a reference to a temporary.

Comment: The fact that it also happens with a `glm::vec3` indicates that you have some UB somewhere in your code. We can't help you if you don't show us said code.